# How to implement more and less functionality with dynamic HTML data?

Tags: javascript, html

I have one JSP page where i need to show one DIV having HTML from database table field(its Data Entry Field is a TinyMCE). I have to implement more and less functionality(like http://viralpatel.net/blogs/demo/jquery/show-more-link-shortened-content/). I can't do substring as it may cut some HTML tag in between and some tags may remain unclosed which affects my UI . and i can't show and hide based on the height of DIV as font is controlled by TinyMCE and different lines may have different font-size and this may cause last line to be shown partially.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after fetching and and during the time of displaying apply jquery truncate plugin but make sure to apply the below property to the div

```
word-wrap:break-word
```

Comment: Thanks  Deepak, I took Jquery truncate API and it works thanks alot.